# Py4JJavaError when invoke pyspark distinct

Tags: python, windows, apache-spark, pyspark, jupyter-notebook

I am running a spark script in a course with Jupyter Notebook in Windows 10. I create my session with no problems and invoke the collect for an rdd that we tested.

But when I try to run it with a distinct, I get the following error and I can't figure out how to fix it.

```
import findspark
findspark.init()
findspark.find()

import pyspark
from pyspark import SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("First Level Fundamentals")\
                         .config("spark.driver.extraJavaOptions","--add-opens=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED",)\
                         .getOrCreate()
#spark.conf.set("spark.kryo.registrationRequired","false")
sc = spark.sparkContext

#This Work
num_list = [i for i in range(1,6)]
num_rdd = sc.parallelize(num_list)
num_rdd.collect()


#This fail
list_rep = [1,1,2,3,3,4,5,5,6,6,7,7,7,7]
rep_rdd = sc.parallelize(list_rep)

#Aplied distinct
dist_rdd = num_rdd.distinct()
dist_rdd.collect()
```

This is the error that I get when I make the distinct

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [9], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 dist_rdd.collect()

File C:\spark\spark-3.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\rdd.py:950, in RDD.collect(self)
    941 """
    942 Return a list that contains all of the elements in this RDD.
    943 
   (...)
    947 to be small, as all the data is loaded into the driver's memory.
    948 """
    949 with SCCallSiteSync(self.context) as css:
--> 950     sock_info = self.ctx._jvm.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(self._jrdd.rdd())
    951 return list(_load_from_socket(sock_info, self._jrdd_deserializer))

File C:\spark\spark-3.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9.3-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py:1321, in JavaMember.__call__(self, *args)
   1315 command = proto.CALL_COMMAND_NAME +\
   1316     self.command_header +\
   1317     args_command +\
   1318     proto.END_COMMAND_PART
   1320 answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
-> 1321 return_value = get_return_value(
   1322     answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1324 for temp_arg in temp_args:
   1325     temp_arg._detach()

File C:\spark\spark-3.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\sql\utils.py:111, in capture_sql_exception.<locals>.deco(*a, **kw)
    109 def deco(*a, **kw):
    110     try:
--> 111         return f(*a, **kw)
    112     except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
    113         converted = convert_exception(e.java_exception)

File C:\spark\spark-3.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9.3-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py:326, in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    324 value = OUTPUT_CONVERTER[type](answer[2:], gateway_client)
    325 if answer[1] == REFERENCE_TYPE:
--> 326     raise Py4JJavaError(
    327         "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
    328         format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329 else:
    330     raise Py4JError(
    331         "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}. Trace:\n{3}\n".
    332         format(target_id, ".", name, value))

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 3 in stage 2.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 3.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 19) (T203598.tasa.telefonica.com.ar executor driver): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create serializer "com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer" for class: java.nio.HeapByteBuffer
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.factories.ReflectionSerializerFactory.makeSerializer(ReflectionSerializerFactory.java:65)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.factories.ReflectionSerializerFactory.makeSerializer(ReflectionSerializerFactory.java:43)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.newDefaultSerializer(Kryo.java:396)
    at com.twitter.chill.KryoBase.newDefaultSerializer(KryoBase.scala:62)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.getDefaultSerializer(Kryo.java:380)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.register(Kryo.java:410)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer.$anonfun$newKryo$2(KryoSerializer.scala:141)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:431)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer.newKryo(KryoSerializer.scala:140)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer$$anon$1.create(KryoSerializer.scala:102)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.pool.KryoPoolQueueImpl.borrow(KryoPoolQueueImpl.java:48)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer$PoolWrapper.borrow(KryoSerializer.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializerInstance.borrowKryo(KryoSerializer.scala:346)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializationStream.<init>(KryoSerializer.scala:266)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializerInstance.serializeStream(KryoSerializer.scala:432)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockObjectWriter.open(DiskBlockObjectWriter.scala:157)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockObjectWriter.write(DiskBlockObjectWriter.scala:279)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:171)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.ShuffleWriteProcessor.write(ShuffleWriteProcessor.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:506)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1462)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:509)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.newInstance(DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.java:79)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:483)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.factories.ReflectionSerializerFactory.makeSerializer(ReflectionSerializerFactory.java:51)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field final byte[] java.nio.ByteBuffer.hb accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.nio" to unnamed module @34f5090e
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:354)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.checkCanSetAccessible(Field.java:180)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.setAccessible(Field.java:174)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.buildValidFields(FieldSerializer.java:283)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.rebuildCachedFields(FieldSerializer.java:216)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.rebuildCachedFields(FieldSerializer.java:157)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.<init>(FieldSerializer.java:150)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.<init>(FieldSerializer.java:134)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.<init>(FieldSerializer.java:130)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.newInstance(DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.java:67)
    ... 30 more

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2454)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2403)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2402)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2402)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1160)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1160)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1160)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2642)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2584)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2573)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:938)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2214)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2235)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2254)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2279)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$collect$1(RDD.scala:1030)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:414)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:1029)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala:180)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create serializer "com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer" for class: java.nio.HeapByteBuffer
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.factories.ReflectionSerializerFactory.makeSerializer(ReflectionSerializerFactory.java:65)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.factories.ReflectionSerializerFactory.makeSerializer(ReflectionSerializerFactory.java:43)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.newDefaultSerializer(Kryo.java:396)
    at com.twitter.chill.KryoBase.newDefaultSerializer(KryoBase.scala:62)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.getDefaultSerializer(Kryo.java:380)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.register(Kryo.java:410)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer.$anonfun$newKryo$2(KryoSerializer.scala:141)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:431)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer.newKryo(KryoSerializer.scala:140)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer$$anon$1.create(KryoSerializer.scala:102)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.pool.KryoPoolQueueImpl.borrow(KryoPoolQueueImpl.java:48)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer$PoolWrapper.borrow(KryoSerializer.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializerInstance.borrowKryo(KryoSerializer.scala:346)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializationStream.<init>(KryoSerializer.scala:266)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializerInstance.serializeStream(KryoSerializer.scala:432)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockObjectWriter.open(DiskBlockObjectWriter.scala:157)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockObjectWriter.write(DiskBlockObjectWriter.scala:279)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:171)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.ShuffleWriteProcessor.write(ShuffleWriteProcessor.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:506)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1462)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:509)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.newInstance(DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.java:79)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:483)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.factories.ReflectionSerializerFactory.makeSerializer(ReflectionSerializerFactory.java:51)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field final byte[] java.nio.ByteBuffer.hb accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.nio" to unnamed module @34f5090e
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:354)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.checkCanSetAccessible(Field.java:180)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.setAccessible(Field.java:174)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.buildValidFields(FieldSerializer.java:283)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.rebuildCachedFields(FieldSerializer.java:216)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.rebuildCachedFields(FieldSerializer.java:157)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.<init>(FieldSerializer.java:150)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.<init>(FieldSerializer.java:134)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.<init>(FieldSerializer.java:130)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.newInstance(DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.java:67)
    ... 30 more
```

At some point I read that putting in the org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer might fix it, but that didn't work either

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("First Level Fundamentals")\
                         .config("spark.driver.extraJavaOptions","--add-opens=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED",)\,"--add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED",)\.
                         .config("spark.executor.extraJavaOptions","-Dspark.serializer=org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer",)\,"-Dspark.serializer=org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer",)\
                         .getOrCreate()
```

These are the versions I am using for this example

[image]

Does anyone know how I can solve this error?

Comment: It's working fine for me without any additional spark configurations

Comment: Mohana, in production it also runs smoothly, but this particular practice locally fails us because of this problem. Do you know how we can fix it?

Comment: I checked stacktrace which you posted, error says - `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create serializer "com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer" ` have you specified this config anywhere in code or spark-submit or config files?

Comment: I tried putting this config("spark.executor.extraJavaOptions","-Dspark.serializer=org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer",)in the session, but in that case, I fail any invocation of the collect. At the moment I don't know what other configuration I could add.

Comment: Some where it's specified too use custom kryo serializer - `com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer` it's causing the issue